# Eliminating J operation in assembly?

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, riscv

In the following question what will happen  if I didn't write Exit? I assume it will continue to Else branch, is that right? or it will skip all branches until it reaches code outside a branch?

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to include the image directly here, sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must mean if you didn't write `j Exit`, since eliminating `Exit:` would result in an assembly error.  I suppose you could remove both..

If you eliminate that `j`, logically such program would execute both the then-part and the else-part, which is bad form for an if-then-else.

It would effectively translate into:

```
if (i == j)
    f = g + h;
f = g - h;
```

Which as you can see destroys the control structure of the original if-then-else.

---

Each and every single instruction informs the processor of what instruction to execute next.  Most instructions (the ones that don't branch) tell the processor to advance the program counter by 4, which instructs the processor for sequential execution of the next instruction in memory.

There is no magic, this is very predictable and well-defined — explicitly in terms of updates to the program counter.  A 32-bit `add` instruction has two consequences: it does the add and updates the target register, ***and***, it increments the program counter by 4.  And as I mentioned, each and every instruction similarly has its "main" effect, as well as an effect on the program counter, which tells the processor exactly what to do next.

---

The processor doesn't see labels, so, taken alone, labels have no representation in the machine code.  A *usage* of a label (e.g. `j Exit`) is translated into the machine code as a number, here with `j` as a delta the processor would have to add to the program counter to accomplish the jump.